# Symfony could not find driver using docker

Tags: docker, symfony

I'm trying to create symfony 5 project using docker with a container for mysql, phpmyadmin, symfony and maildev.

Here is my configuration in the `docker-compose.yml` :

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: ruakh_db
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
        networks:
            - dev

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin:latest
        container_name: ruakh_phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
        networks:
            - dev

    maildev:
        image: maildev/maildev
        container_name: ruakh_mail_dev
        restart: always
        command: bin/maildev --web 80 --smtp 25 --hide-exetensions STARTTLS
        ports:
            - 8081:80
        networks:
            - dev

    apache:
        build: php
        container_name: ruakh_www
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
            - ./:/var/www
        restart: always
        networks:
            - dev

networks:
    dev:

volumes:
    db-data:
```

The `Dockerfile` configuration to create the server :

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev;

RUN echo "en_US.UTF8 UTF8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar dom mbstring zip gd xsl
RUN pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

WORKDIR /var/www/
```

The issue i'm struggling with is that whenever I want to run a `php bin/console make:migration` it throws me this error :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 128: An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

I assume that it has something to do with my `.env` and my server can't manage to connect to the database.

Here is the `.env` :

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://ruakh_mail_dev:25?verify_peer=0
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@ruakh_db/ruakh?serverVersion=5.7"
```

How could I manage to resolve this error ?

I can run queries to the database and fetch data from a controller.

But I can't run `php bin/console make migration` but the `php bin/console make:entity` is working

here is the `config/packages/doctrine` :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '13'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

### EDIT

Today I just opened and tried again and it seems like the error had change here is the error I got now :

> **In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:**
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name > resolution

I find a solution to avoid my problem. Whenever something is about the database I run the commands from the docker containereven if it's not what I was looking for. So I keep this post open in case someone have an answer.

Comment: In my `Dockerfile`, I use docker-php-ext-install `mysqli` and noticed that you don't, maybe that could be the cause ?

Comment: I rebuilt the image with the mysqli and the problem still persist

Comment: Could you provide a file  `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` ?

Comment: Yes of course, I added it

Comment: Can you ping your db instance from your apache instance using container name?

Comment: Yes I can connect to mysql withing the apache instance. I believe this has something to do with the host since I can query to the database from a controller but I can't migrate using commands from the host

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better understanding of docker will help you get why it's working inside the container and not from your machine.

When you declare services in `docker-compose.yml` each service will have a DNS name which is the `container_name` so when you are inside one of the containers `ruakh_db` is reachable, that's why your controllers are able to access the database.

But when you are outside the containers `ruakh_db` has no meaning as your machine will not be able to resolve the DNS name. That's why your command line wont work.

One solution is to configure your OS to make `ruakh_db` point at your localhost.
Doing so depends on the OS you are using, but generally it consists of adding this line to your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1     ruakh_db
```

Follow this link for more information on how to change your hosts file depending on your OS: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

You should then configure your MySQL container to expose  an external port, so it's reachable from outside :

```
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: ruakh_db
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    networks:
        - dev
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
```

You also should have mysql extension on your machines`php-cli` installed to be able to talk to your mysql database.